# RSpec auto loading behavior for gems

Tags: ruby, rspec, autoloader

I have a gem project with rspec configured. My folder structure looks like this -

```
lib/
  - foo/
    - foo.rb
    - alpha.rb

spec/
  - spec_helper.rb
  integration/
    - alpha_spec.rb
```

The files `foo.rb` and `alpha.rb` have the following structures in terms of class definitions.

```
# lib/foo/foo.rb
class Foo
  # do stuff
end
```

and

```
# lib/foo/alpha.rb
require_relative 'foo'

class Foo
  class Alpha
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

The main takeaway here is that `Alpha` is a nested class that requires 'foo.rb' directly. (Someone using it would `require foo/alpha` from their script)

My `spec_helper.rb` file simply requires my library by loading `foo/alpha` -

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb

# Check if `Foo` class is already defined
Object.const_defined?('Foo') ? puts "IS DEFINED" : "IS NOT DEFINED"

require 'foo/alpha'
```

To my surprise, the constant `Foo` was already loaded even before requiring `alpha/foo`, as the output returned `IS DEFINED`.

Because of this, my `require` statement tries to load `alpha.rb` which in turn requires `foo.rb` and that errors out with

```
foo.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': Foo is not a class (TypeError)
```

According to [this thread](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/1859), that type of error is raised by RSpec when a class (`Foo`) is already defined.

How is this happening? Does RSpec attempt to do some magic behind the scenes and load my library? How do I get around this?

**EDIT**: I also removed the `--require spec_helper` line from my `.rspec` file so it's only getting loaded manually when I run the test.

Comment: Are you using this gem with Rails? This error sounds like the ones that get created by Rails autoloading. Rails creates modules for namespaces automatically, so in Rails it is best to avoid having the same constant for both namespaces and classes.

Comment: Hey @LauraPaakkinen - I am not using Rails, this is just a standalone gem.

Comment: I was asking since the error seems to suggest that, when ruby starts loading the `foo.rb` file, the constant `Foo` has already been loaded and it is not a class (maybe a module? or just some other constant). AFAIK RSpec itself doesn't have any autoloading features. I tried the example you gave and I wasn't able to reproduce the error. Are you sure there is no `Foo = ...` anywhere else in your code by accident?